# Projection in .find() not working for MongoDB/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an express app that's supposed to query my MongoDB database, then return only certain fields of the result. My code for this currently looks like this:

```
app.get('/stored', (req, res) => {
    let pollId = req.query.id;
    let pollCursor = db.collection(collName).find({"_id": ObjectId(pollId)}, {"_id": false, "pollName": false}).toArray((err, data) => {
        if(err) return err;

        let dataObj = data[0];
        console.log(dataObj);       
    });
});
```

I expect to recieve a data object that contains all fields except the '_id' and 'pollName' fields. However, the object I get still contains both these fields, as well as all the other fields. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Projection within the `find()` is deprecated. Use [`Cursor.project()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#project) instead.

Comment: This worked, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The first you have to test like this:

```
    app.get('/stored', (req, res) => {
        let pollId = req.query.id;
         res.send(pollId)
         return;
    });
```

if pollId match with pollId from client send, it's fine. You should create a query to find like this:

`let query = {_id: pollId}`

This is my code, hope help you

```
 // https://tudiendanhngon.herokuapp.com/author/detail?id=5adc963c7b76157c65d3b1d9
    app.get("/author/detail", function (req, res) {
        var id = req.query.id;
        var query = {_id: id};
       db.collection(COLLECTION_AUTHORS).find(query).exec(function (err, author) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("Error")
            } else {
                res.json(author);
            }
        });
    });
```